# Tic Tac Toe: Human Vs Computer

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

The problem that I am struggling with right now is trying to get the computer to move in a random spot after the human picks the first move. Towards the bottom of the code, I am trying to set the computer to make a random x and y value but I also need to check to make sure that the computer doesn't randomize a spot that is already taken. so Ill im tryin to do is fix that last else statement at the bottom and I should be good. Can anyone figure out what I need to do? Thanks!

```
#include<iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
char board [3][3] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',}; // This is going to create the 3X3 board for the X's and O's to be placed
bool playing = true;
int x,y; // the X and Y will correspond to the rows and columns
int randomX, randomY;

while (playing) {

   for (int i=0;i<3; i++){
    for (int j=0;j<3; j++){
        cout<<board[i][j];
        if (j<2)
            cout << "|";
    }
    if (i<2){
    cout<<endl;
    cout << "-----";
    cout << endl;
    }
   }
   cout << endl << "Where would you like to move? ";
   cin >> x >> y;
   board [x-1][y-1] = 'x'; // When the user is asked to place a X in a certain box, the values they enter will be subtracted by 1 so that it corresponds to the location on the board

    if (board [0][0]== 'x' && board [0][1]== 'x'){
       if (board [0][2] == 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [0][2] = 'o';// This is the start of all the rows being checked
    }
    else if (board [0][0]== 'x' && board [0][2]== 'x'){
       if  (board [0][1]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [0][1] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [0][1]== 'x' && board [0][2]== 'x'){
        if  (board [0][0]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [0][0] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [1][0]== 'x' && board [1][1]== 'x'){
         if  (board [1][2]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [1][2] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [1][0]== 'x' && board [1][2]== 'x'){
         if  (board [1][1]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [1][1] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [1][1]== 'x' && board [1][2]== 'x'){
         if  (board [1][0]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [1][0] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [2][0]== 'x' && board [2][1]== 'x'){
        if  (board [2][2]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [2][2] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [2][0]== 'x' && board [2][2]== 'x'){
         if  (board [2][1]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [2][1] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [2][1]== 'x' && board [2][2]== 'x'){
         if  (board [2][0]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [2][0] = 'o';// this is the end of all the rows being checked
    }
    else if (board [0][0]== 'x' && board [1][0]== 'x'){
         if  (board [2][0]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [2][0] = 'o';// this is the start of all the columns being checked
    }
    else if (board [0][0]== 'x' && board [2][0]== 'x'){
         if  (board [1][0]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [1][0] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [1][0]== 'x' && board [2][0]== 'x'){
         if  (board [0][0]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [0][0] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [0][1]== 'x' && board [1][1]== 'x'){
         if  (board [2][1]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [2][1] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [0][1]== 'x' && board [2][1]== 'x'){
         if  (board [1][1]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [1][1] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [1][1]== 'x' && board [2][1]== 'x'){
         if  (board [0][1]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [0][1] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [0][2]== 'x' && board [1][2]== 'x'){
         if  (board [2][2]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [2][2] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [0][2]== 'x' && board [2][2]== 'x'){
         if  (board [1][2]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [1][2] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [1][2]== 'x' && board [2][2]== 'x'){
         if  (board [0][2]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [0][2] = 'o';// This is the end of all the columns being checked
    }
    else if (board [0][0]== 'x' && board [1][1]== 'x'){
         if  (board [2][2]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [2][2] = 'o';// This is the start of checking for diagonals
    }
    else if (board [0][0]== 'x' && board [2][2]== 'x'){
         if  (board [1][1]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [1][1] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [1][1]== 'x' && board [2][2]== 'x'){
         if  (board [0][0]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [0][0] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [0][2]== 'x' && board [1][1]== 'x'){
         if  (board [2][0]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [2][0] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [0][2]== 'x' && board [2][0]== 'x'){
         if  (board [1][1]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [1][1] = 'o';
    }
    else if (board [1][1]== 'x' && board [2][0]== 'x'){
         if  (board [0][2]== 'x')
            playing = false;
            else board [0][2] = 'o';
    }
     else {

        srand(time(0));
        randomX = rand()% 3;
        randomY = rand()% 3;
        board [randomX][randomY]== 'o';
     }

    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on *minimal*.

Comment: Things that won't work, do nothing or behave different than you seem to expect : `board [randomX][randomY];`, `do{...}while{...}`, `if (...) /* something with no ; */ else}`. If you have (not unreasonably) left things to be implemented, then please make them more obvious by the use of comments.

Comment: hint: when there are X pieces already placed, there are `3*3 - X` free tiles, you only need to roll one random number to pick it (from 0 till `3*3 - X -1`) not several in a loop

Comment: I recommend to use consistent indentation to your advantage.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are currently trying to "fix" the last else statement.
Fixing means: You want the Computer-player to change the Value at "`board [randomX][randomY]`".

Currently you are doing three things:

1. Initialize a Random number generator.
2. Get 2 random indices as a location.
3. Compare that position to `'o'`. (the `==` makes this a comparison. It does not change the value.)

What you probably want to do:

1. Initialize this once, very high up. And not actually with a Constant, since the Computer would always play the same numbers, otherwise.
2. Set your random position to the value `'o'`.

Use 
`[randomX][randomY] = 'o';`
instead of 
`[randomX][randomY] == 'o';`

Also you should probably check, if the position already has a value in it. Otherwise you would simply override whatever was in it before.

And you need to test, if the Computer won, after this.

Oh. And your `return 0;` is in the while loop. It should probably be outside.

Lastly: Look at the Comments under your Post. There are a few good / interesting suggestions there. E.g. you could use one random number between 0-8 instead of two times 0-2.

Especially the formating suggestion: Instead of your formating, consider using:

```
    if  (board[1][0] == 'x')
        playing = false;
    else 
        board[1][0] = 'o';
```

Be consistent and also indent your code accordingly.

I hope this helps.
Cheers.